# Using Facebook Session to login my website?

Tags: facebook

I am using facebook to login and register into my website. But I want to know that how can I use facebook session to create session on my website and as soon as user logs out of facebook the user will be automatically logged out of the website too.

Plz help.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Facebook's Real Time API (See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/).  Maybe you can subscribe to their log out event.